# Storing String Array as JSON Array then getting Ljava.lang.String@ when trying to receive and set TextView as value

Tags: android, json, string, arrays

Right now i am pulling a value from a EditText MainActivity and putting that as at string in sharedpref. In a later activity I am receiving that value and trying to add it to the end of an array that is contunially growing. To store the Array in that later activity for receiving later to continue adding I used a JSON array. So basically I create a String Array when the counter is 0 (first input the user has done since clearing) and receive the string value from the MainActivity EditText and add that as the first value in the String Array and then store it as a JSON Array. When I receive it later (when counter is > 0) and convert it back to string Array, the outPut in my TextView for any given spot in the array is [L.java.lang.String;@42a5e438,. Below is my code for both if coutner == 0 and counter >0; Does anyone know what the solution is?
        int placeCounterExplanation = pref.getInt("placeCounterExplanation",0);
                 //getting new item
                 String explanationItem = pref.getString("explanationItem",null);

```
         if(placeCounterExplanation > 0){

         ///////////////////////////////////// RECEIVE//    

                    //pull existing array
                    JSONArray explanationjArray;
                    try {
                        explanationjArray = new JSONArray(settings.getString("jArray", ""));
                    //converting from json back to workable string array
                  // String []ExplanationDetailArray = new String[explanationjArray.length()];
                        String []ExplanationDetailArray = new String[100];
                    //matching them/converting
                    for(int i = 0, count = explanationjArray.length(); i<= count; i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            String jsonString = explanationjArray.getString(i);

                            ExplanationDetailArray[i] = jsonString;

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    //after matching^ it adds newest value
                    ExplanationDetailArray[placeCounterExplanation] = explanationItem;
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // getting attached intent data
                    String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
                    // displaying selected product name
                     txtProduct.setText(product);

                    if (product.equals("Alcohol")){



                        test.setText(ExplanationDetailArray[0]);
                        String placeCount = Integer.toString(placeCounterExplanation);


                    test2.setText(ExplanationDetailArray[1]);

                    //  test3.setText(placeCounterExplanation - 1);

                    }


                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    /////STORE
                    explanationjArray.put(Arrays.toString(ExplanationDetailArray));
                   // explanationjArray.put(ExplanationDetailArray);

                    editor2.putString("jArray", explanationjArray.toString());
                    editor2.commit();

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

         }











         if (placeCounterExplanation == 0){
             ExplanationDetailArray = new String[100];
             ExplanationDetailArray[0] = explanationItem;
             JSONArray explanationjArray = new JSONArray();
            //////////////////////////////  



            // String sC =  Integer.toString(spotCounter);




                Intent i = getIntent();
                // getting attached intent data
                String product = i.getStringExtra("product");
                // displaying selected product name
                 txtProduct.setText(product);

                if (product.equals("Alcohol")){


                    test.setText(ExplanationDetailArray[0]);
                //  test2.setText(ExplanationDetailArray[1]);

                //  test3.setText(placeCounterExplanation - 1);

                }






             ///////////////////////////////
             //STORING MIGHT NOT NEED THIS INSIDE HERE
            // explanationjArray.put(ExplanationDetailArray);
              explanationjArray.put(Arrays.toString(ExplanationDetailArray));

            editor2.putString("jArray", explanationjArray.toString());
            editor2.commit();

        //  placeCounterExplanation = placeCounterExplanation + 1;
            // editor.putInt("placeCounterExplanation",placeCounterExplanation);
             //editor.commit();

         }


         //after either IF Statement catches teh program, it advances the counter.
         placeCounterExplanation = placeCounterExplanation + 1;
         editor.putInt("placeCounterExplanation",placeCounterExplanation);
         editor.commit();
```

Comment: After making that change, I only am getting the first value of my array to come out correctly? Any ideas?  And when i go to add a second, it shows null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is coming from the following line in code :
explanationjArray.put(ExplanationDetailArray);

This will insert a textual representation of the object into the JSON array. Instead you can do :
explanationjArray.put(Arrays.toString(ExplanationDetailArray));
or your own implementation of converting the string array to a concatenated set of strings.

Comment: After making that change, I only am getting the first value of my array to come out correctly? Any ideas?